# Query to fetch all tables in a Schema/DB, that have a specific column VALUE

Tags: sql, db2-luw

Is there a query to display all tables that have a specific column VALUE?

I know how to fetch all table that have a specific column, but i want to extend this to find a specific value and then update the corresponding results to change that value.

```
select c.tabschema as schema_name,
       c.tabname as table_name
from syscat.columns c
inner join syscat.tables t on
      t.tabschema = c.tabschema and t.tabname = c.tabname
where c.colname = 'START_DATE' and c.tabschema='sample'
and t.type = 'T'
*<AND 'START_DATE' ='2017-05-17' >*--NOT SURE HOW WE DO THIS PART??
order by schema_name,
         table_name;
```

Then i wanted to issue an update on the resulting tables, to update the column 'START_DATE' VALUE, something like below

```
UPDATE <ALL RESULTED_TABLES FROM ABOVE QUERY> SET START_DATE = '2017-05-09' WHERE Tables = <ALL RESULTED_TABLES>
```

Comment: See DB2 manual [Dynamic SQL applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_dynamicsqlapplications.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write an application that uses dynamic SQL in order to pull that off.  There are a number of different interfaces for Db2 that will allow you to do this including embedded SQL, CLI, ODBC, Python, Perl, etc.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_dynamicsqlapplications.html

Answer (score 0):

You could write a stored procedure or compound SQL.
Take your SQL to gather all tables having the START_DATE column and loop over this list.
Within the loop you could then do an EXECUTE like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || resolved_tablename || ' SET START_DATE="<my_new_startdate>" WHERE START_DATE="2017-05-17"'
```